# How to handle Callback URL with 'POST' in VueJs 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuejs3

Am using Vue.js 3, i have a case related with transaction with external site. This site asked me to provide a url callback (suppose it: `https://example.com/callbacktransaction`) which they will make a POST after transaction success. I have dig some documentation and also monitoring other questions but no luck. Anyone could give me advice for this issue? How can i handle this url callback

Comment: a payment callback should not be handled on frontend, it's not possible to set Vue route as a `POST`

Comment: how about if i handle that in cloud functions, but how can i communicate with FE? by using dcumentsnapshot?

Comment: no idea about documentsnapshot. for communication between fe and be/function could use websocket